# Authentication with FireAuth when pulling data from FireStore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm getting a problem with my authentication class.
I log my new user through Firebase Auth, and I try to pull his data from Firestore.
The auth part is working great, but I get redirected to the `Homepage` because of my `StreamBuilder` before getting the data from the Firestore.

How can I log my user and get his data BEFORE getting redirected?

Authentification Class.

```dart
//...
final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

// Login with email and password.
  Future<UpstrideUser> loginWithEmail({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      final User user = result.user!;
      final DocumentSnapshot doc =
          await _firestore.collection('userData').doc(user.uid).get();
      final UpstrideUser upstrideUser = UpstrideUser.fromFirestore(doc.data()!);
// ...
},}
```

StreamBuilder

````dart
Future<Widget> getLandingPage() async {
  return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          snapshot.hasData ? print(snapshot.data!.uid) : print("NO ACTIVE");
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Homepage();
          } else {
            return const Login();
          }
        }
        return const Login();
      },
    ),
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the final `return const Login()` in your code. This redirects you before the data has loaded from Firestore.

You'll typically want to show a loading indicator in this phase, so for example:

```
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
      snapshot.hasData ? print(snapshot.data!.uid) : print("NO ACTIVE");
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Homepage();
      } else {
        return const Login();
      }
    }
    return const CircularProgressIndicator(); // 
  },
```

Comment: Hello @Frank 
Unfortunately, I am still redirected to the `Homepage` **before** getting my data from Google Firestore
I do think the issue comes from my `StreamBuilder` listening for auth change (authStateChanges)  and the fact that I need to use the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method  (which triggers the `authStateChanges`) to get my user UID to get the Firestore data.

So what happen is that I'm getting redirected on the homepage (since for FireAuth, I am connected) but the async request to the Firestore is not yet finished.

Comment: @BLKKKBVSIK if that's the case then all you need to do is await the async request to Firestore, correct? If that solved your issue might I suggest making your own answer so you can accept it in a few days?